# Environment variables in Slack App installation?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there the notion of environment variables during Slack App installation?

Here is a fabricated use case.

Let's say we have a company that resides in 3 regions.  There is a REST API to search for employees in region via these endpoints:

```
GET https://us.cars.com/findemployee
GET https://uk.cars.com/findemployee
GET https://it.cars.com/findemployee
```

Say we develop a Slack App with Slash Command feature to search for employees, like:

```
/findemployee
```

When a user installs the Slack App in his workspace, is there a way for the user to select what region he belongs?  Then somehow store this as environment variable in the Slack App installation.  So that when the user executes the slash command `/findemployee`, it will be calling the respective REST API url.

For example, if the user selects uk region during installation, then the slash command `/findemployee` will send request to `GET https://uk.cars.com/findemployee`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The app installation process is fully controlled by your app, with the app code running on your own (virtual) server (not run by Slack). So you can of course use environment variables if you want to.

However, from an application design perspective I would suggest to rather store this kind of information in a database, e.g. by having an object for each workspace in your database. That object would then contain the chosen region for the particular workspace (or user).

Once a user issues a slash command, Slack will send a request to your app with all the information about the current user and workspace. Your app can then decide to call the right API based on that input, e.g. for each region.